# executing java code from php

Tags: java, php

Ok so i'm trying to develop a program that reads some data from a router which i'm accessing, and then uploads this data into a mysql database.I need a php page to display this data and perform further analysis on it. I want the user to access only the php page. Which means that when the url for the php is typed, the php page should automatically execute the java code and perform the database update operation.

I have tried the exec command like this:

```
<?php
    $command = "D:\Code\java TelnetRouter";
    echo exec($command);

?>
```

Its showing me a blank page and not updating the database, so i'm obviously doing something wrong. Any way i can refine he use of the exec command? or another better way to access java through php?

Comment: maybe cd D:\Code then java TelnetRouter

Comment: Maybe "java D:\Code\TelnetRouter"

Comment: If you are expecting a multiline output you probably want to utilise the [second parameter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) - otherwise try [`shell_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: does the user php is running under have the appropriate permissions? Is php just interfacing with your dataset? If so could php and java be seperated? Php could just be an easy way to view your mysql data and java could just import data from your router to mysql

Comment: tried cd D:\Code then java TelnetRouter and even java d:\code\TelnetRouter.

Comment: tried above mentioned variations. Showing the same error :( infact, even this is throwing an error..                                                <?php
 $command = "cd D:\Code";
    $result= shell_exec($command);
 if($result)
  echo 'execution successful';
 else echo 'error' ;
?>
how do I know about the permissions the user is running on? The thing is, the software that we're trying to develop specifies that the user should get certain results after running a url. So if i separate java and php, then the java program will have to be executed separately, which i want to avoid.

Comment: @user3799135 if you are getting a success message you are either doing your php wrong or the java is failing and not returning the correct exit code. I would say to help with your own debugging you might try making or using a java program you wrote yourself to see what one is failing

Answer (score 0):

php [passthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) or [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) can only be  string attributes as command. try running the same command in your terminal , before using it in your code. These functions simply gives your input to the terminal, so the input should be an actual terminal command.

The file should be executed as java and also should be compiled.

try compiling the file.//hope you are trying to execute a .java file.

```
echo exec("C:\mywork> javac HelloWorld.java",$output);
echo exec("C:\mywork> java HelloWorld",$output);
```

Comment: The array() $output is the output you will get when you run the code in terminal. If you want to update the database from java code , you should use some driver like jdbc , etc to do it from java.

Comment: My java code uses jdbc to connect to the mysql database and updata data in one of the tables. I have tested the code independently and it works perfectly. when i run it from cmd using the "java TelnetRouter" command, the database gets updated. The point is, i need the code to be called from a php file.. which is why im using the exec command. but when i run the php file containing the exec command in my browser, i get the output Array() which makes no sense because thats not the output i get when i run the code in the terminal.. and more importantly the database is not updated.. need a fix..

Comment: There may be a permission issue . Do you have the php_java extension? try this http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.java.php
and this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/